# Set values from response to environmental variable array

Tags: environment-variables, postman

I have a Postman POST request, where response body looks like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "object": "Answer",
        "id": 507,
        ...
    },
    {
        "object": "Answer",
        "id": 208,
        ...
    }
],...
```

In following DEL request this ids should be used in body as array:

```
{
"ids": [id1, id2]
}
```

How can i get these ids from response and store it as environment variable array `[id1, id2]` so then it could be used like `"ids": {{answer_ids_array}}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture the `id` values as an array and set in an environment variable you could add something like this to the `Tests` tab of the first request:

```
let myArray = []
_.each(pm.response.json().data, (item) => {
    myArray.push(item.id)
})

pm.environment.set("idArray", myArray)
```

To use the array in the request body, you would need to add this to the `Pre-request script` to transform to saved string back into an array:

```
pm.environment.set("ids", JSON.stringify(pm.environment.get("idArray")))
```

Your request body would then be something like this:

```
{
    "ids": {{ids}}
}
```